# Google Search is showing different results than the metatags

Tags: drupal, seo, meta-tags

In a Drupal project, the title and description is set with the module Metatag. The meta data is correct in the inspector but Google is showing a different result. This is the case for all sites on the page.
This is not because of changes and Google needs to reindex as this is data from the cached page.

Google seems to add *- EMU'en* to the end of the title although the meta tag and title doesn't have it. Furthermore, the description is ignored and the site content is shown instead.

There is only one metatag for each and not multiple title tags.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO. This is not a good candidate for Webmasters as this has already been asked and answered there.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Google Search uses `og:title` and `og:description` for their search result snippets?

Answer (score 1):

This is how Google algorithms work now! Google prefers to show the meta description and title which is more relatable to the query, so sometimes its automatically pick it from the content.